# Sending an html file with json AND having the browser reload that json without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

I am trying to write a browser-server program where the browser sends an http get to 'http://localhpost:3000/param=something'. The server should return an html page and a json. I tried using res.render() where I pass the json as a parameter (it is an array) but render won't work. Here's my code in app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

and here's the index.js which answers the http request:

```
router.get('/:screen', function(req, res, next) {
var arr = Array();
res.render('main.html', { playlist : arr });
});
```

The error I get is:
**Error: Cannot find module 'html'**

Now, even if that works, I still have to somehow get an updated json (the array) from the server every minute **without reloading the page**. I succeeded in doing that partially where I access the main json (the array) that is stored in the shared library and load it using ajax. That works, but the program needs to get a sub-json of that one that is relevant to the 'screen' parameter that was sent in the original http get.
In order to do that I need a way to make the server re-calculate the sub-json from the original one and re-send it to me without reloading the page.

As to research and things I've tried:
**Problem 1**: I searched a lot through this site and found a couple of solutions that none worked for me. It might be a version problem or anything else that I'm not paying attention to but I've made all the changes I'm supposed to in order to make 'render()' work on html. I just kept getting this error.
**Problem 2**: As I've already explained, I found a way to get the original json but can't figure out how to get the sub-json. here's the code in main.html (which is sent back regardless of the parameter 'screen' as part of the original get request):

```
$.get("http://localhost:3000/ads.js", function(data, status){
    playlist = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

I would very much appreciate any help regarding any of these problems.

**Note:** I included those two problems in the same question because they are connected to each other. Both requests should make the server calculate a sub-json and send it. One request will send it back as part of an html file and the other will be loaded into that page without reloading the whole page. Solving one of these problems directly affects the other so I chose to include them both here.

Comment: in one request, the response from the server can be HTML **or** JSON - you can't do both in the one response - well, you can, but then it's not really html or json, it's just **data** which has to be processed on the client

Comment: The json doesn't have to be sent separately. I was trying to send it with the html page using 'render()' so it can be added to the page as a variable. As long as it can be accessed by the html page at the browser, all methods are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so here's how I solved all those problems:

- As for the render() function I learned that you need to change your view engine somehow so I didn't use it.
- Instead, I sent the main html file to all stations using 'sendFile()'. Inside that html file I included ajax requests (which kept the site from reloading). I set the 'url' to 'window.location.href' which included the parameter needed.
- At the server side I used separate functions for dealing with requests. One that sends back the main html file and the other calculates the sub-json using the parameter in the url and sends it back to the user.